# Moving mouse cursor from windows service

Tags: c#

I have a windows service that creates and runs socket server on windows 8.1 desktop. I want to move mouse position on desktop when request is received from the client but setcursor(x,y) method doesn't work. It only works when I call it in the main function of the class.

What are my options ?

Comment: A service is not associated with a desktop. it runs as "Desktop 0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Services run in an isolated session separate from interactive processes. They can't interact directly with the UI. Generally the best solution is to run an interactive client app which talks to the service (via a named pipe or such). The service can pass the mouse information to the interactive client which can call SetCursor, SendInput, etc. as needed.

Comment: Hi @Rob. I too am looking to set mouse events via service. I created an application to set the mouse position based on coordinates passed by the service. But it does not seem to work.